# httphandler redirect goes in infinite loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have a httphandler which intercepts any pdf file request present inside a folder called "calderdale" and redirects the user to login page. This is how I m redirecting

```
  if (memberLoginName == "UNKNOWN" && !isDomainFallthrough)
        {

            // Check if the user is logged in, if not redirect to Login page.
            context.Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?retUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.Url.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
       // download file
         }
```

e.g. The initial request is made for "http://local.knowledge.scot.nhs.uk/calderdale/1.pdf"
and the return url becomes "http://local.knowledge.scot.nhs.uk/Login.aspx?retUrl=http://local.knowledge.scot.nhs.uk/calderdale/1.pdf"

as the return url also contains "calderdale/1.pdf" this url is intercepted again and this goes in infinite loop. 
Any ideas how can we stop this going in infinite loop? thanks

Comment: Can't you detect if the url contains ~/Login.aspx and break the loop at that point?

Comment: Based on your description, it sounds like you're just searching the string for the address. Instead, you should try to parse the string into a URI, and only examine the path portion.

Comment: Try removing the last character off the redirect URL and see if it loops. That is, confirm that you're getting back into your handler because the file type appears to be ".pdf".

Comment: Was my answer helpul? If so, accept it so others can use it as well. If it wasn't, did you find a different solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can think of, is how the HttpHandler gets called.. why is it detecting the url in the query string?

Other then that, there is a very simple solution to your problem (giving it's really caused by the url in the query string).
Instead of using UrlEncode - convert the string to Base64 and the login url will look as following:

"http://local.knowledge.scot.nhs.uk/Login.aspx?retUrl=aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsLmtub3dsZWRnZS5zY290Lm5ocy51ay9jYWxkZXJkYWxlLzEucGRm"

For more information about how to encode and decode strings to and from base 64: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/mneiter/archive/2009/03/22/how-to-encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-c.aspx